# Can I run multiple processes on admin user account while logged in to another account on OSX Server (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, osx-server, server.app, serveradmin

I am setting up a Mac mini home server as an HTPC and to run other processes (FileMaker Server, web dev server, etc.). I want to make a user with limited privileges to be logged into while Mac mini is connected to TV. However, I want other processes to be running on admin user account while I'm logged in to user with limited privileges. Is this possible or do I have to be logged in to the admin user to run the processes?

Comment: You mean 'will processes still run on one account whilst that account is backgrounded?' Yes - but I don't get the point of logging yourself into a limited account after that, as you still know the admin password for any other task you need to do & can simply type that in when asked.

Comment: I want to be able to be running automatic backups, a dev server, execute Hazel rules, and a number of other things through the admin user login. However, while the computer is connected to the TV, any user in the house can access it, so I want to be logged in on a general account without privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The services that are installed/managed via Mac OS X Server can run in the background and do not require a GUI login session. The Server application itself is just a config/monitoring tool and does not need to be running for the services to run. So it is quite OK to run those services and have a limited user logged into a GUI session.